# Android AutoCompleteTextView with List<String>

Tags: android, list, adapter, autocompletetextview

I have an `AutoCompleteTextView` where the user types an address. I want to be able to show suggestions below as he types. To do that I get a list of possible addresses via the Reverse Geocoding API. i want then to show this list of strings (possible addresses) to the user. Just like the google maps app does.

I have added a `TextChangedListener` to the `AutoCompleteTextView`. On the `onTextChanged()` event an `AsyncTask` is executed where the list of possible address gets updated on the `onPostExecute()`.

```
autoText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        new GeoTask().execute();
    }
});
```

**Attempt 1**

This is the list:

```
static List<String> suggestionList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And this is the code for the adapter for the `AutoCompleteTextView` :

```
autoText.setThreshold(3);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, suggestionList);
autoText.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
```

With the above code nothing shows up.

**Attempt 2**

I also tried using an array as an argument for the adapter and every time the list of address gets updated I convert it to the array.

```
static String[] suggestions;
static List<String> suggestionList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Adapter:

```
autoText.setThreshold(3);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, suggestionList);
autoText.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
```

AsyncTask:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
...
suggestions = suggestionList.toArray(new String[suggestionList.size()]);
super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
}
```

How can i make it work? Is there a way to use the adapter with the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why nothing shows up is because the list is empty and in `onPostExecute` of your AsyncTask your only assigning new array  to your `suggestions` reference, what you should really do is use adapters methods to add and remove elements. You can try this code:

```
adapter.clear();
adapter.addAll(/*new collection of suggestions*/);
```

in your `onPostExecute` method.

**NOTE:** `adapter.addAll()` method appeared only from 11th API, so if you use lower, then you would have to add each item manually.